Can I find the reason for why Get-Item or Test-Path fails?
There are tons of posts about how to use Test-Path or [System.IO.File]::Exists() to verify if a file or folder exists. However, these posts fall short in giving any nuance. The following will return true:
Test-Path -Path "\\Server\Share\path that exists"

This will return false:
Test-Path -Path "\\Server\Share\path that doesn't exist"

But this will also return false:
Test-Path -Path "\\Server\Share\path that exists but can't be access because network issues"

I thought I could instead use Get-Item and the catch the error message to use the type of error to determine if the path was just inaccessible, or if it truly doesn't exist. However, Get-Item just returns ItemNotFoundException even when the target path should exist but is inaccessible.
Is there any way to distinguish an inaccessible path from one that truly does not exist?
EDIT: Windows already have system error codes that can tell you if the file was not found, or if it was a network issue, or if access is denied etc. I'm looking for a way to use this level of detail in figuring out why a path was not reachable in Powershell.

How would a remote computer know of a "path that exists but can't be access because network issues" if it cannot access it?  If there is a network issue, e.g., router is down, and the path is inaccessible, would this remote computer somehow access some magical cache of all paths that once were accessible to it and assume that this path still indeed does exist and offer this different error message?  I'm really trying to wrap my head around how this could be possible.

A quick thought: First test for "\Server\Share" to detect network issues (if you know for sure \Server\Share exists). Then test for the sub directory to detect path-not-found issues. You could even ping "Server" as a first step, to detect if it's alive and only then test for the share.

So what whould you expect it to return if the path is inaccessible and some one just change or removed the path/file from somewhere else?

Why wouldn't it know the reason? Windows already knows this with error codes. net helpmsg 5 = access denied, net helpmsg 2 = file not found, net helpmsg 53 = network path not found, etc. Since Windows is already able to distinguish these situations, I would expect there to be some way in Powershell to also do that.

This is an experiment, but seems to work well:
The following PowerShell function utilizes the .NET DirectoryInfo class to check the existence of a path and handle exceptions that provide more detailed information about the failure.
function Test-NetworkPath([string]$Path) {
   try {
      $dirInfo = [IO.DirectoryInfo]::new($Path)
      if ($dirInfo.Exists) { Write-Host 'Path exists.' }
      else {
         Write-Host 'Path does not exist.'
         # Attempt to access the directory to trigger an error for further diagnosis
         $null = $dirInfo.GetDirectories()
      }
   }
   catch [System.ArgumentNullException] {
      Write-Host 'Path is null.'
   }
   catch [System.ArgumentException] {
      Write-Host 'Path contains invalid characters such as ", <, >, or |.'    # .NET Framework and .NET Core versions older than 2.1
   }
   catch [System.IO.PathTooLongException] {
      Write-Host 'Path is too long.'
   }
   catch [System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException] {
      Write-Host 'Directory not found.'
   }
   catch [System.Security.SecurityException] {
      Write-Host 'Path is inaccessible due to: Caller does not have the required permission.'
   }
   catch [System.IO.IOException] {
      Write-Host 'Path is inaccessible, likely due to network issues.'
   }
   catch {
      Write-Host ('Unexpected error: {0}' -f $_.Exception.GetType().FullName)
   }
}

Explanation:

$dirInfo = [IO.DirectoryInfo]::new($Path)

Get directory info, and possibly throw error if $Path is incorrectly formed.


if ($dirInfo.Exists) { Write-Output 'Path exists.' }

Simple if exists check.


$null = $dirInfo.GetDirectories()

Attempts to returns the subdirectories of the non-existing $Path.
Throws a fairly informative error.



Valid path:
Test-NetworkPath '\\ValidServer\C$\ValidFolder'

Output:
Path exists.

Invalid folder:
Test-NetworkPath '\\ValidServer\C$\InvalidFolder'

Output:
Path does not exist.
Directory not found.

Non-existent Server (Network error):
Test-NetworkPath '\\InvalidServer\C$\SomeFolder'

Output:
Path does not exist.
Path is inaccessible, likely due to network issues.


Yes, this does exactly what I was looking for! I tried to trigger these types of nuanced error messages with Get-Item and Get-ChildItem but those commandlets has a lot of built-in fault tolerance that I don't want (for example, if -Path is null or empty, it will default to the current location, which in my use case gives an incorrect return, etc.) Thanks a lot for your help!

One improvement I found is that the [IO.DirectoryInfo]::New() will actually work on paths longer than 246 characters and find the path, but .Exists will still say false because it's too long. So I added an if($Path.Length -gt 246){#use Get-Item here just in case} section and removed the path too long exception. One interesting thing is that -Path $Null still says "invalid characters". Access Denied for me throws System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException and not SecurityException.

@TanakaSaito, that is odd!  I didn't test for those scenarios, and largely used the info found here.   But on the other hand, that isn't completely surprising.  The way I came up with System.IO.IOException for network was that I tried a non-existing server and that is the error it gave.  Also, now that I'm thinking about it, I placed System.IO.IOException last on purpose, PathTooLongException inherits from it.  Didn't test this, but I assume the order is important.

I thought finding info on why you are getting MethodInvocationException would be easy to find, but so far it isn't.  But oddly enough, searching for it without "PowerShell" still brings up a lot of PowerShell related issues.  Makes me wonder if PowerShell is the actual source and not DirectoryInfo or GetDirectories, but I don't understand how that could be.  If I find time today, I might try a few experiments and see if get the same error.

I might have spoken too soon, the error category is MethodInvocationException but the Fully qualified error ID is UnauthorizedAccessException which makes a lot more sense.

Short answer: no. You are basically asking how to know if a path in a USB drive exists... while the drive is not connected.
Longer answer: sorta? The best you can do is to first check the connection with Test-Connection or something else which, in case of failure, should give you an explanation for the failed connection.
Which MIGHT be enough in your case, if you just need to manage whether a path is unavailable because connection issues.
